# How to properly *connect* background socket at iPhone startup in a VOiP application?

Tags: iphone, ios4, background, startup, voip

I'm using a VOiP Socket in my iPhone application. I manage to get it working properly, both in background mode, or when the application is in the foreground.

My issue is **at iPhone startup: how to be sure that the iPhone has network access (3G or wifi) in order to properly connect the socket without bothering the user ?**

**Details**: a VOiP application is supposed to be started automatically as soon as the iPhone starts : this is working ok, the `didFinishLaunching` is invoked right after the iPhone startups. But at this time, the user may not have entered his pin code (so that 3G isn't available) and wifi may not be available. 
Is there any technique to `start` automatically the VOiP Socket when network access is ok ?

**My current approach that fails** : in the `didFinishLaunching` I keep on trying to start the VOiP socket every 5 secs. If it takes too long without managing to get the connection, the OS is going to kill the app, (max 20s to start), but as the app is flagged as "VOiP", it's going to be started again, and so on...
After a while, once network is OK, the socket is being created , connected and everything seems to works ok, *EXCEPT* that when data comes to the socket, my callback `didReceivedData` is not invoked (I display a local notification as soon as I get something from the socket for debug purpose) .

Then, if **I start the application just 1 time**, and then quit it (home button), so that the application is put in the background, in that case, the socket callback is properly invoked and I see local notifications being displayed, proof that the socket is properly waken up in that case.

**I would like to get the VOiP socket up and running right from iPhone startup (once network is OK) without having the user to launch the application 1 time. Any idea about how to achieve this ?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the Reachability class to poll for connectivity every X seconds, THEN try to connect.

Reachability won't take as long as creating the VoIP socket will.

Comment: why not but how can you poll for reachability in the background ? As this is not a VoiP / location etc (standard background tasks) , I wonder how I can achieve such a Long-Running background task like "poll reachability" ? Maybe as implementing a "Completing a Finite Length Task in the Background" as described in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW12 ? The issue is that the "applicationDidEnterBackground" is not called at boot time :/

Comment: Hi, "Completing a Finite Length Task in the Background" can be startet at any time, like I discovered. That means, you could create your backgroundTask at startup. SO you'll get up to 10 Minutes to do your Socketconnections!

Comment: With a little delay.... thanks Jack, I'll try this, I read about this in another SO thread and this is an interesting thing to try.